# Javascript scrollTop bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have written the most basic scrollTop function to move the page focus down to the content of the site - skipping past the header / nav / hero images, if the page is page number 2,3,4,5,6... of products.

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("/?sf_paged=") > -1) {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".searchandfilter").offset().top
    }, 2000);
};
```

If I run this in my console (before implementing into live code) the page operates as expected - moves to the element I state and positions it to the top of the page.

However, here is where my question lies: Once I place this in my code to run on ready (implemented into my footer scripts) it passes the element I wish it to scroll to (stops 3/4 of the way down the page not 1/4).

I need it to stop when it hits the element not afterwards - I know this code works, why might this be happening?

Comment: Try running your script on `load` instead of on `ready`

Comment: Do you have more than one `.searchandfilter` element in your HTML? Is one of them created by JavaScript after `ready`?

Comment: `ready` fires when the DOM parser reached `</html>` tag, but **before** all your assets (including images) loaded. So scrolling at that time will scroll you to the wrong position. Scroll when all resources loaded and DOM knows correct sizes of all elements. On `window.load` event.

Answer (score 0):

As HerrSerker and Andrei have brought to light - running on load allows the elements above to have loaded before it decides to scroll down the page.

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("/?sf_paged=") > -1) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(".searchandfilter").offset().top
        }, 2000);
    };
});
```

Thank you for bringing your solutions you have helped a whole lot of brain ache.